# How to send HTML form by Ajax, save data to file and display them in div

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm new to Web Development. I'm learning `JavaScript` now(`JQuery`) and I chose Simple Chat as a project to get started.
Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to prevent the page from refreshing after a message is sent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Chat</title>

    
   
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Chat room</h1>
   <div id="status"></div>
    
    <form id="send" class="ajax" action="action.php" method="POST">
         <label for="fname">Type your message</label>
         <input type="text" id="fname" name="myMessage">
         <input id="upload" type="submit" name="myButton"value="Submit" />

    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
    var formData = {
      name: $("#fname").val(),
      
    };
    var posting = $.post(url, {
  name: $('#fname').val(),
});
/* So far, just listing whether the Form has managed to prevent its classic sending */
posting.done(function(data) {
  $('#result').text('success');
});

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
    </script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
 $path = 'messages.txt';
 if (isset($_POST['myButton']) ) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a");
    $string = $_POST['myMessage' ];
    fwrite($fh,$string . PHP_EOL); 
    fclose($fh); 
 }
?>
```

I have created a text file `messages.txt`, where I want to save newly created messages using Ajax.
I would like the newly added message to be displayed on the page below the chat( in the `div` with `id #result`)

Comment: I think in your submit function, you'll want to prevent its default submit with `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: In submit function is `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: I think it's coming too late in the function, but the time that line is reached, the form's already called its default action.

Comment: The prevention of default submition works great, but my problem is, that data from text `input`,form does not write into the file

Comment: I'm not familliar with php, but does it show you any errors? I'm seein g`fwrite($fh,$string . PHP_EOL); ` - is the second arguments supposed to be `$string . PHP_EOL`? or should the `.` be a `,`?

Comment: `. PHP_EOL` just creates new line, it does not show any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for advices, this is how I have solved it

```
$("#send").submit(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $messageSent = $("#send").serialize();
       

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'action.php',
    data: $messageSent,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To save data to file in PHP with this jquery ajax code, try this:

```
<?php
    $path = 'messages.txt';
    if (isset($_POST['name']) ) {
      $fh = fopen($path,"w");
      $string = $_POST['name']. PHP_EOL;
      fwrite($fh,$string); 
      fclose($fh); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: I assume, that `name` in `$_POST` and in `$string` is `myMessage` in my case?

Comment: No, you sending throught ajax this data: 
var formData = {
      name: $("#fname").val(),
};

Then you must use $_POST[‘name’] in php, because $_POST[‘myMessage’] not exist in PHP.